Lisa's future travel plan
In 2000 Lisa visited Houston in Arkansas.
Very next year she went to the Hindukush mountains in Connecticut.
In 2009 decided to visit Panama city in Hawaii.
In 2017 took an interesting detour to the town of Pahrump in New York.
Few years later she was in Camden in Pennsylvania.
A week from now she will be in California for 3 months.
Which town?  Paris or Metz or Dublin? Why?

You're assuming that she won't have a sudden change of plans and return to Pahrump.

The answer is

 PARIS

Reason:
Ok so what we have here in order

 are US presidents: the dates they were in power, the US president’s last name and their place of birth


 2000 CLINTON HOUSTON BORN IN ARKANSAS.
 2001-2009 BUSH HINDU KUSH BORN IN CONNECTICUT.
 2009-2017 OBAMA PANAMA CITY BORN IN HAWAII.
 2017-2021 TRUMP PAHRUMP BORN IN NEW YORK.
 2021- BIDEN CAMDEN BORN IN PENNSYLVANIA.

And so last but not least

 We have the current presidential candidate (Kamala) HARRIS PARIS BORN IN CALIFORNIA

Just to add

 Lisa is hinting a LISA SIMPSON who was portrayed as being the first female president in the SIMPSONS to show.


rot13(Ohg jba'g Ovqra fgvyy or gur HF cerfvqrag arkg jrrx?)
